# 3D Line Plot with Datavisualization

Tags: qt, qt5, qtquick2

I am looking for a way to draw a 3d line plot. Preferably I would like to use the datavisualization framework, but it does not seem to provide this out of the box.

I experimented a little bit and ended up using 3D surface plots (Surface3D) displaying the lines as surfaces (i.e. ribbons) like this:

[image]

While this works and looks okay in above picture the thickness of the line depends on the perspective. Rotating the plot always allows to find the angle where the line disappears since it has not thickness:

[image]

Is there a type of plot that would be better suited for this? I tested the bars which don't perform well for lots of samples and don't look nice in my application. I also tested scatterplots which are not suitable either.

If there isn't: Where would I start to implement this myself on top of the existing classes in the datavisualization framework? I am thinking about adding another surface "ribbon" in z direction, however that seems a little hackish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the technique described as hackish above. While I am not too happy about the approach the overall look is quite okay:

[image]

So basically each data line consists of three QSurfaceDataRows that together form two 90° ribbons as can be seen here:

[image]